I can't make my command hyperlink a figure
I have make two distinct commands for crossreferencing equations and figures, which are the following
\usepackage{graphicx, xparse, hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textcolor{blue}
{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}}
%command for referencing equations


\RenewDocumentCommand{\figref}{mO{}}{
\hyperlink{\ref{#1}}{\textcolor{blue}
{\textup{\tagform@{Fig.\ref{#1}#2}}}}}
%command for referencing figures
\makeatother

the command for referencing equations let's me click the equation number and it takes me to that part of the document, but, whichever way I tried to modify the figure reference command, it does not let me (and this is what I believe is the closest I've been to achieve it), instead it takes me to the first page of the document instead of the figure I'm referencing.
Here's a MWE
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, xparse}, hyperref, fixdif, amsmath, amssymb}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textcolor{blue}
{\textup{\tagform@{\ref{#1}}}}}
%command for referencing equations


\RenewDocumentCommand{\figref}{mO{}}{
\hyperlink{\ref{#1}}{\textcolor{blue}
{\textup{\tagform@{Fig.\ref{#1}#2}}}}}
%command for referencing figures
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Métodos matemáticos II}
\author{M.G.A., Transcrito por: R.N.B.}
\date{2024}

\maketitle

\newpage

here you have an equation

\begin{equation} \label{eq:vol_def}
    \int_\text{i}^\text{f}{\d V}=\Delta V
\end{equation}

which I am going to reference \eqref{eq:vol_def}

and here we have a figure

\begin{figure}[H]

    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{something.png}

    \begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
        \caption{hello world}
        \label{fig:haha}
    \end{minipage}

\end{figure}

And let's say now I wanna reference the figure, which I am going to do via \figref{fig:haha}. This proceeds to take you back to the first page.

\end{document}


Why aren't you (a) running \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue} and (b) using ordinary \eqref and \ref commands to create hyperlinked cross-references to equation and figure environments, respectively? No need to define \figref or to redefine \eqref.

you should test your MWE. It errors in various places.

@Mico I'm not doing that because I also reference other thing in the text apart from equations and figures, and I only want those to be in blue, not all. And I've created this commands because when I reference a figure I want it to appear as (\text{Fig. } subsection.\arabic{figure})

Are you familiar with \autoref?

@Teepeemm no, I am not, I will read about it, thanks.

Rather than re-invent the wheel, why not just (a) add the instruction \hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue} in the preamble and (b) use unmodified \eqref and \ref commands to create cross-references to equation and figure environments, respectively?

For an in-depth discussion of LaTeX packages that help with the job of creating cross-references, please see the posting Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict? Several cross-referencincg packages --  including hyperref and cleveref -- provide commands that let you include both the word label (say, "equation" or "figure") and the number in the hyperlink.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\eqref' macro
\usepackage{hyperref} % make cross-references into hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue}

\begin{document}

Here we have an equation:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:simple}
    1+1=2.
\end{equation}
I can cross-reference it as equation \eqref{eq:simple}.

And here we have a figure.
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{cow}
    \caption{Hello bovines.}
    \label{fig:haha}
\end{figure}
I can cross-reference it as figure \ref{fig:haha}.

\end{document}

